# Using factory in a $scope defined method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to `AngularJS` and `Ionic` but I'm starting with ionic 1 ATM. I'm trying to define a function inside my controller for a login view page that only activates when clicking the submit method. Using the directives I found this is how it looks:

```
    <ion-view title="Login" id="page5">
      <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        <h4 id="login-heading8" style="color:#000000;font-weight:400;">Por favor introduzca su teléfono:</h4>
        <form ng-submit="send()" id="login-form1" class="list">
          <ion-list id="login-list1">
            <label class="item item-input" id="login-input1">
              <span class="input-label">Teléfono:</span>
              <input type="tel" placeholder="" ng-model="formData.phoneNumber">
            </label>
          </ion-list>
          <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
          <input value="Acceder" type="submit" id="login-button1" style="border-radius:1px 1px 1px 1px;" class="button button-positive button-block">
        </form>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

So the only way I found was to actually make a new function inside my `$scope` otherwise it will always call my function even if I haven't clicked my button yet. So controller looks something like this:

```
    .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'httpService', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams, httpService) {
      $scope.formData = {phoneNumber : ""};
      $scope.send= function(httpService){
        httpService.getCall("http://localhost:8000/Hermerest/web/app_dev.php/api/parents?telephone=" + $scope.formData, loginCtrlCallback);
      }
    }])
```

And as you can see I'm trying to use a factory method that I've defined to avoid using the same code over and over again, but injecting httpService through parameters to the `$scope.send()` seems to not work as it appears as undefined.
This is my code in for the factory:

```
    .factory('httpService', function($http){
      return {
        getCall: function(url, callback){
          $http.get(url)
            .success(function (response) {
              alert(response);
              //callback(response);
            })
        },

        postCall: function(url, data, callback){
          $http.post(url, data)
            .success(function (response) {
              alert(response);
              //callback(response);
            })
        }
      }
    })
```

As I'm newbie I can accept any suggestions or fix that I could try, thank you in advance guys!

Comment: You do not need to pass the service as the function parameter. As you have already defined the dependency in the controller, you can use it anywhere in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, catch the promise from the controller instead of the factory. And no need to use callback since `promise` returns the data into the controller.

And need to return the `$http` from the factory also.

```
 getCall: function(url){
   return $http.get(url);
 }
```

in controller use `then` instead of `success`. it is deprecated since angular 1.4

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'httpService', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams, httpService) {
      $scope.formData = {phoneNumber : ""};
      $scope.send= function(){
        httpService.getCall("http://localhost:8000/Hermerest/web/app_dev.php/api/parents?telephone=" + $scope.formData)
         .then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data); 
          })
      }
 }])
```

Comment: How is the `promise` relevant to question?

Comment: since he try to make the factory common it is better to use the promise inside his controller

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't notice it was deprecated! Also this kinda of simplifies more my code, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add httpService as function parameter. It is available in your controller, since you have injected it as dependency.

So simply do this:

```
 $scope.send= function(){
    httpService.getCall("http://localhost:8000/Hermerest/web/app_dev.php/api/parents?telephone=" + $scope.formData, loginCtrlCallback);
  }
```

Comment: This was also helpful!! Thank you so much!!